# Jasper report passing List<List<?>> passing as Javabean in subreport

Tags: jasper-reports, javabeans, subreport

I am beginner with Jasper report, and I got this below situation. I know this topic habe been discussed here but seriously speaking I went through many topic, tried, but no luck, some how I am not able to make it. Please help me...

Situation:  I need to pass a `List<List<?>>` from my java layer to Jasper to make a PDF. Some post I saw people suggested to use SubReport and in Some post people suggested to use List component in JasperReport. I tried both and finally messed up. Please suggest which one to use to make my work done, and it will be very grateful if any one can pass the source code or complete clear Idea how to implement this. I need this to print like below:

```
1.Patient Name: abcd
    Test Name: GlucoseTest     Result: 24    Ref.Range: 10-30 mg/dl
    Test Name: TSH             Result: 0.5   Ref.Range: 0.1-0.9 mg/dl

2.Parient Name: efgh
    Test Name: GlucoseTest     Result: 24    Ref.Range: 10-30 mg/dl
    Test Name: TSH             Result: 0.5   Ref.Range: 0.1-0.9 mg/dl
    Test Name: GlucoseTest     Result: 24    Ref.Range: 10-30 mg/dl
    Test Name: TSH             Result: 0.5   Ref.Range: 0.1-0.9 mg/dl

3.Parient Name: efgh
    Test Name: GlucoseTest     Result: 24    Ref.Range: 10-30 mg/dl
.
.
.
```

and so on...

Please help, i am puzzled, thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I haven't used JasperReports from sometime now, but as far as I remember, in this situation, SubReport is the right choice. If you want, you can send me your report file and I'll see what's wrong & why it won't work.

Secondly, there is another option which I don't recommend, you can merge your two lists into one, like this:

```
Patient Name: abcd Test Name: GlucoseTest     Result: 24    Ref.Range: 10-30 mg/dl

Patient Name: abcd Test Name: TSH             Result: 0.5   Ref.Range: 0.1-0.9 mg/dl
```

Then create a group by 'Patient Name' in Ireport to filter it and print it exactly the way u want.

Comment: First of all, A big thank u Sir, for your reply. I would be very glad if u can see my reports code and help me out, can you please provide me your email id so that I can send you my codes of report. Merging two list wont fit my requirement, here I gave sample example... I have to show lil more info in report. If u see my code u will understand... please let me know your email Id.

Comment: Yes sure: ethanmarcusdev@gmail.com